# How I can call report and display underneath panel in Java application?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I prepared a report on iReport Designer. How i can call this report in my Swing based Java application, and display underneath panel in my swing based java application?

Comment: Unrelated but why do you use the "ı" character instead of "I"?

Answer (score 0):

The report itself is just a JasperPrint of course, but you can look into JasperViewer and try to use that component to embed the report into your app.

[JasperView API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JasperViewer.html)